# Программное управление параметрами печати для WebBrowser

Tags: c#, wpf, реестр, print

Добрый день!

Возникла следующая задача: есть WPF-окно, на котором стандартный WebBrowser.
При загрузке окна в нем отображается xml/xslt через `NavigateToStream`. Для отображаемых данных реализована функция печати через `mshtml`:

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = WBrowser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
doc.execCommand("Print", true, 0);
```

Проблема: при печати игнорируется css-background.

Нашел решение через модификацию диалога параметров страницы в реестре:

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser
        .OpenSubKey("Software", true)
        .OpenSubKey("Microsoft", true)
        .OpenSubKey("Internet Explorer", true)
        .OpenSubKey("PageSetup", true);

var defaultValue = regKey.GetValue("Print_Background");
regKey.SetValue("Print_Background", "yes");
```

Вопрос: возможно ли решить проблему без модификации реестра?

Спасибо!